# Excel vba get month from Date object

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell that gets filled with a date value. I then store it in a variable.

```
Sub dateTest()
    Dim min_date As Date
    min_date = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(22, 5).value

    MsgBox (min_date)
End Sub
```

However, I would like to get a month and a day separately from that object. How to do it?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=316:excel-vba-date-time-functions-year-month-week-day-functions&catid=79&Itemid=475). And [Método WorksheetFunction.Days (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-days-method-excel).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Month()` and `Day()` are the functions that you need:

```
MsgBox (Month(minDate))
MsgBox (Day(minDate))
```

- [Microsoft Month Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s70thwaz(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [Microsoft Day Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b4h8sxy(v=vs.90).aspx)

---

Another way is to use the Format function:

```
MsgBox Format(minDate, "m")
MsgBox Format(minDate, "d")
```